# DaVinci Resolve 12.5.5 - Deselect Power Window

Tags: davinci-resolve, keyboard-shortcut

When you're in the Color tab and have an active Power Window selected in the Viewer, is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle it on/off to see the unencumbered view of your clip?

"Deselect All" doesn't seem to deselect all.

Comment: I don't have Resolve on this machine, but I'm pretty sure there's a little box on the lower left of the viewer window where you can choose what overlays you see. Set it to none and you can work on your power window without it appearing.

Comment: yikes - my bad - I meant is there a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the key combination: Shift + `  (*Shift and Backtick*) to toggle the Power Window overlay on the [**Color**] page.

This also works for viewer overlays on the [**Edit**] page in Resolve 16.